# Java EE 6 + JPA - Exception: Message Driven Bean cant be managed bean

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, glassfish-3, stateless-session-bean, message-driven-bean

I create an `Enterprise Application` `CustomerApp` that also generated two projects `CustomerApp-ejb` and `CustomerApp-war`. In the `CustomerApp-ejb`, I create a SessionBean call `CustomerSessionBean.java` as below.

```
package com.customerapp.ejb;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class CustomerSessionBean {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "CustomerApp-ejbPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    public void persist(Object object) {
        em.persist(object);
    } 
}
```

Now I can deploy `CustomerApp-war` just fine. But as soon as I create a Message Driven Bean, I cant deploy `CustomerApp-war` anymore. When I create `NotificationBean.java` (message driven bean), In the `project destination` option, I click add, and have `NotificationQueue` for the `Destination Name` and `Destination Type` is Queue. Below are the code

```
package com.customerapp.mdb;

import javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty;
import javax.ejb.MessageDriven;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;

@MessageDriven(mappedName = "jms/NotificationQueue", activationConfig =  {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue")
})
public class NotificationBean implements MessageListener {

    public NotificationBean() {
    }

    public void onMessage(Message message) {
    }

}
```

The server log said `Message Driven Bean cant be managed bean`. Well I did not mean it to be managed bean. I did not have `@ManagedBean` in the code????

**EDIT:** Here is the server log

```
[#|2010-06-03T10:02:08.172-0400|SEVERE|glassfishv3.0|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=24;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|Exception while loading the app org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: Message Driven Beans can't be Managed Beans
at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:169)
at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:125)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:224)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:338)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:183)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:272)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:305)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:320)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1176)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$900(CommandRunnerImpl.java:83)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1224)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:365)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:204)
at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:166)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:100)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:245)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:637)
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.DefinitionException: Message Driven Beans can't be Managed Beans
at org.jboss.weld.bean.SessionBean.checkEJBTypeAllowed(SessionBean.java:313)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.SessionBean.initialize(SessionBean.java:122)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.AbstractBeanDeployer.deploy(AbstractBeanDeployer.java:111)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.deployBeans(BeanDeployment.java:151)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:367)
at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:167)
... 30 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The Exception is `DeploymentException: Message Driven Beans can't be Managed Beans`

This is [a bug in GlassFish 3.0](http://forums.java.net/jive/thread.jspa?threadID=75957) which is fixed in 3.0.1.

- workaround: remove the `beans.xml` (but this will disable CDI)
- real solution: download [a promoted build](http://download.java.net/glassfish/v3.0.1/promoted/) of GlassFish 3.0.1 (the problem is reported as being fixed in version 3.0.1-b9 so any superior version should work)

Below the initial answer:

---

- Where is the MDB located? Did you put it in the `CustomerApp-ejb`?
- What do you mean by *Now I can deploy `CustomerApp-war` just fine*? You're supposed to deploy the Enterprise application (`CustomerApp`).
- What do you see in the GlassFish logs when the deployment fails?

Comment: I just updated my post with the server log. Thanks you very much. The Exception is `Message Driven Bean can't be Managed Bean`

Comment: Super. That fix it. I got one last question if you dont mind. On you website, you have glassfish and glassfish-web. What are the different between those two?

Comment: @Harry Java EE 6 introduced the notion of *profiles* which are subsets of the entire Java EE 6 specification and specified a [Web Profile](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/JavaEE/JavaEE6Overview_Part3.html#tab1). The Web Profile is already very rich but you don't get JMS in it for example. glassfish-web implements the Web Profile.